# checking values in an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array:

```
int array[5];
```

And I am going to use this array to put some values in it. Now my question: how do I check whether something has been filled in the array at place i after filling in some numbers? Thank you

Comment: Initialise with a known value and compare whether it's different, surely?

Answer (score 5):

There's no such "elegant" way.

The only way to do this is to have some special value, that will indicate "not filled". For example,

```
int array[5] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
```

The other option is to have a bitmap, which will tell you which positions are filled, which - not.

Answer (score 2):

The array contains values from the moment it is instantiated, so you cannot query it to check whether it has been "filled". But you could keep a separate data structure to keep track of which elements you have filled. Or you could wrap the array and the other data structure in a class that allows you to assign values to the array *and* check whether they have already been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an other array saving if case '**i**' has been filled or not.

```
int array[5]
bool filled[5]={false}; 
array[0] = 42; 
filled[0] = true;
```

But it's quite dirty.

Comment: There's no need from another `int` array. It's a waste of memory. Some "bitmap" could be used.

Comment: Of course, I edited using boolean (better), but how would you use a bitmap ? I mean, what data structure would you use ? A integer array eight times smaller ?

Comment: I'd use an array with some fixed size type. For example, array from `uint8_t` and use bitwise operations, to check each bit. In other words, encode 8 elements in 1B (1 per each bit).

Comment: Yes, I wanted to say a char array eights time smaller. But it's the same with uint8_t.

Comment: @JérômeBoé It is better to use a type that expresses it's *actual* length in this case. Yes a char is an octet on every consumer platform, but the standard does not guarantee or require this. A `char` *is* a "byte", but the standard uses that word to mean a unit of storage the size of a `char` *not* a unit of storage 8 bits in length.

Answer (score 0):

as it's C++ why not use a container of std::pair?

one element of the pair is a boolean  (true if value is set), and the other one is the needed value.

Answer (score -1):

well you must  ask if your array in  position "i" is ==NULL something like this

```
int array[5];
int main()
{
    array[0]=1;
    array[1]=2;
    array[3]=1;
    for(int i =0; i < 6;i++)
    {
        if(array[i] != NULL)
        {
            cout<<"Value is: "<<array[i]<<endl;
        }else{
            cout<<"The Value is NULL"<<endl;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `NULL` is just `define` of `0`. There could be a value `0` in the arrey, which may be valid.

Comment: He can iterate through it, right, but what else? Nothing. Does not answer the question.